# How to join tables with silex and PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, silex

actually I'm trying to join three tables with PDO via Silex.
But I don't know exactly how to do it.

media_movies.php

```
private $id;
private $title;
private $titleOriginal;
private $realisator;
private $plot;
private $actor;
private $country;
private $type;
private $genre;
private $releaseDate;
```

in my cinema_session.php :

```
private $id;
private $idmovie;
private $idTheater;
private $language;
private $date;
private $subodels;
```

and my cinema_theater

```
private $id;
private $name;
private $numberOfPlace;
private $address;
private $phone;
```

there's my get route

```
$app->get('/ListSessions', function (Application $App) {
//should i change it , but by what ?
$status = $app ['repo.Sessions']->getAll();
return $app['serializer']->serialize($status, $app['format']);
```

my getAll function

```
public function getAll() {
  $result = $this->db->query('SELECT m.title, m.runnigTime, s.date, t.name as theater
  FROM media_movies m, cinema_sessions s, cinema_theaters t');
return $result->fetchAll();
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with Silex, PHP (PDO) or MySQL. Your problem is that you should learn how to properly create JOIN queries in plain SQL.

In your query: `SELECT m.title, m.runnigTime, s.date, t.name as theater FROM media_movies m, cinema_sessions s, cinema_theaters t` the problem is that you are creating a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) (cartesian product, which basically means all possible combinations of grouping all records from tables m, s and t).

Instead you just need to tell your JOIN by which field you want the create the join (I'm assuming the id fields) so you should end up with something like:

```
SELECT m.title, m.runnigTime, s.date, t.name as theater 
FROM media_movies m, cinema_sessions s, cinema_theaters t 
WHERE m.id = s.idMovie 
  AND s.idTheater = t.id;
```

Notice that you can write that using the INNER JOIN syntax (some prefer this syntax):

```
SELECT m.title, m.runnigTime, s.date, t.name as theater 
FROM media_movies m INNER JOIN cinema_sessions s ON m.id = s.idMovie
    INNER JOIN cinema_theaters t ON s.idTheater = t.id;
```

You should probably read about joining.